# Add CSS Class to DIV based on Y position of cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The page I'm working on: http://working.studioas-cc.com/

Here, there are a list of project titles. On hover of a project title, it shows their featured image **below**.

I want to position these images **above** the title, if the Y position of the mouse cursor is below 50% of the browser window height.

I think I need to add an additional class to the span to re-position it, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "onmousemove" event to track mouse position inside the webpage. Given that, compare it's Y position with the window height and change the  class accordingly.

Here's the event listener to give you a jump start:

```
document.onmousemove = function(event) {
  // X position of cursor
  event.x;
  // Y position of cursor
  event.y;

  if(event.y < (window.innerHeight/2)) {
    // do something with image classes
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

I suggest to put the event listener inside a Timeout for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery (I saw you already use it) to accomplish this.

```
$(theTextElement).hover(function(e) {
  //Mouse Over Event
  //The Mouse Y Position
  var y = e.pageY;
  //The window height
  var windowY = $(window).height();
  //The mouse is past the halfway point of the screen
  if((windowY/2)<y){
    //Toggle the class
    $(theImageElement).addClass('viewTop');
    $(theImageElement).removeClass('viewBottom');
    //Show the element
    $(theImageElement).show();
  }
}, function() {
    $(theImageElement).hide();
});
```

This is based on the assumption that you want to solve the positioning with CSS.
You would have to add some code to figure out which image to show etc.

Let me know if some things are unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you'll want to stick to your current implementation i.e `span` elements hidden until hovered over.

You can get each element's y position using

```
elem.getBoundingClientRect().top
```

which returns the distance from the top of page.

You can get the height of the window using `window.innerHeight`.

So it's just a matter of checking for each element if its top position is greater than half the height of the window

```
elem.getBoundingClientRect().top > window.innerHeight/2
```

If the above is true then you could assign the element a class to appear above the link title, but honestly there are quite a few way's to accomplish the same thing.

So, let's say you want to add a class to the spans to appear above the title, you could do something like either relative positioning them and add a negative `top` css value or what I would do is to use css3 transforms

```
.above {
  transform: translate(0, -100%);
}
```

and this way you don't need to second-guess the height of the span since css transforms use the dimensions of the target element and not the parent container.

Another thing to keep in mind is that, in order to keep the script load to a minimum, maybe you'll want to check the position of the `span` element in the `onhover` event listener and not check all these spans when the DOM is ready since they will pause rendering until the script is ready and make the page feel unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already know about event.target, window.innerHeight and event.clientY, using position:fixed and positioning relative to the targets position is one way of going about it.